# HTTP to HTTPS redirect issue .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm a newbie to coding and I'm using following codes in my .htaccess.

My issue is my site is not redirecting from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` with this code. Did research but couldn't find something that goes with my code.

I do not know if this is the correct order, or the most efficient way to achieve this. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Remove WWW, from both HTTP and HTTPS an force HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Hide .php, and redirect .php files to new non-extension URLS

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^.?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php(/.+)?$ /$1%{PATH_INFO} [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go and let us know if it works out for you. looking at your .htaccess for your SSL looks like it has way more in it then there needs to be. This is what I use and seems to work fine

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect all traffic to an https://

Comment: Really appreciate this. This seems to be working alone. But how do I embed it in my code, because I want the WWW to be gone from both HTTP and HTTPS as before.

Comment: @Gihan www will be gone from HTTPS but not HTTP as HTTP will be redirected straight to HTTPS anyway? if this makes sense.